# How to analyse more then one character in the string for use in a switch?

Tags: java, string, switch-statement, break

Below is my switch statement which take the string 'tops':

```
switch (tops) {

            case "m":
                if (size.equals("m")) {
                    mb += 1.00;
                    to += "Mozzarella";
                } else if (size.equals("l")) {
                    lb += 1.50;
                    to += "Mozzarella";
                }
                break;

            case "o":
                if (size.equals("m")) {
                    mb += 0.80;
                    to += "Olives";
                } else if (size.equals("l")) {
                    lb += 1.20;
                    to += "Olives";
                }
                break;

            case "h":
                if (size.equals("m")) {
                    mb += 1.40;
                    to += "Ham";
                } else if (size.equals("l")) {
                    lb += 2.10;
                    to += "Ham";
                }

                break;
            case "p":
                if (size.equals("m")) {
                    mb += 1.00;
                    to += "Pineapple";
                } else if (size.equals("l")) {
                    lb += 1.50;
                    to += "Pineapple";
                }
                break;

            case "s":
                if (size.equals("m")) {
                    mb += 0.80;
                    to += "Spinach";
                } else if (size.equals("l")) {
                    lb += 1.50;
                    to += "Spinach";
                }
                break;
            default:
                to = "default";
                break;
}
```

At the moment my switch is only anazylizing the first character from the string and not all of them to see if they contain the letters for the cases.

for example if i entered "ms" for tops i would get the correct output but if i entered "msmh"
it does not and results to default or terminates

Comment: In `switch` if you can not do that. Use `if...else if...else` instead

Comment: Your example is not correct. If the string `tops` contains `"ms"` then the switch case for `"m"` doesn't match. Switch for strings always compare the whole string not the first characters.

Comment: There is no need of to write `if` statement @aahung

Comment: At the moment your switch is already way too complicated. You should rather ask how to simplify that whole thing...

Comment: the if statements in the switch is to find out if the size of the pizza is med or large.

Comment: i don't want to look at the string as a whole i want to look at the characters in the string and pick out the correct ones for the case to work

Comment: Just loop over all characters in the string and at each iteration do your `switch` on the current character.

Answer (score 0):

To analyze more then one case in java, you must put the second case before the break which is equivalent to `else if(boolean || boolean)`

For Example:

```
case "B": 
case "C":
{
    //CODE
    break;
}
```